# mod_pagespeed not inserting image dimensions

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-pagespeed

I've added the following:

```
ModPagespeed on
ModPagespeedEnableFilters insert_image_dimensions
```

However, my image still appears as follows:

```
<img alt="WordPress" src="wp-admin/images/wordpress-logo.png" height="20px" pagespeed_url_hash="818906537">
```

No width has been inserted here.

(Page URL https://www.medexpress.co.uk/journals/readme.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like image dimensions are not being inserted because mod_pagespeed is unable to fetch your images. mod_pagespeed must be able to fetch the image in order to know how large they are to be able to insert the correct dimensions. There are a number of reasons that fetching can fail. See the bullet list at the bottom of this [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/faq#not-rewriting) for some of the most common reasons.

The best solution to the problem though, if your environment allows it, is to enable [`ModPagespeedLoadFromFile`](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/domains#ModPagespeedLoadFromFile). This allows mod_pagespeed to fetch files directly from disk, instead of over HTTP, which can increase reliability and performance.